# Error after upgrade - The profile xyz does not exist

Tags: installation-profiles

I have the following error message after updating from Drupal 8 to Drupal 9 and the page no longer react:

```
[Mon Aug 15 21:11:12.605618 2022] [php:notice] [pid 22144:tid 139845594764864] [client 127.0.0.1:39008] Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\\Core\\Extension\\Exception\\UnknownExtensionException: "The profile xyz does not exist." at /home/bavramor/data/Webdesign/Webseiten/xyz.database/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ExtensionList.php line 525
```

Have now tried the following already, but without positive effect:

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3000677
https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2019-05-16/the-module-does-not-exist

Can I somehow change the profile and set it back to default? Or from me also set a completely new. If I would get to that somehow, I can export and import?

Would be very grateful for any help.

Thnx Bavra

Comment: What did you actually try?

Comment: You'll need drush. The simplest option is the [profile switcher module](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile_switcher). If that doesn't work you can try a custom update hook with similar code to the profile_switcher module's. If all else fails, there is a manual option (which by coincidence I had to use on a site yesterday), but it involves manually editing serialised PHP from the database, so not for the faint of heart